# Is it possible to ask series of questions without generate large amount of code?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, while-loop

I am creating a program in Java, using eclipse. The program asks series of questions from the user and until they have answered it correctly it will ask them again and again and, once it gets the correct answer it will store it in a variable for later use. below is my code;

```
int waitseconds;
int favouritenumber;
int hoursofsleep;

do {
    String waitsecondsR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many seconds would you like to wait for out of 1 - 7?");
    waitseconds = Integer.parseInt(waitsecondsR);
}
while (waitseconds < 1 || waitseconds > 10);

do {
    String favouritenumberR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your favourite number out of 1 and 2?");
   favouritenumber = Integer.parseInt(favouritenumberR);
}
while (favouritenumber < 1 || favouritenumber > 2);

do {
    String hoursofsleepR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many hours do you sleep for? between 1-8?");
   hoursofsleep = Integer.parseInt(hoursofsleepR);
}
while (hoursofsleep < 1 || hoursofsleep > 8);
```

These are the first three statements / questions that I have which the user will need to answer and I will probably end up with like 10-12 of these statements in one class, is it possible to make these any shorter? and also I have 2 more questions.

1. Is it possbile to prevent the user from putting in letters answers and if there do, it will provide them with errors? e.g. if there put one instead of 1 or O then the program should ask them to enter again.
2. with the code I have, when you run it a `Input Dialog` and there user has to enter the answer but if the user clicks cancel or cross icon at the top then java is displaying error messages in the console, how can I stop this from happening? like this;

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>         at ExpressTrain.ExpressTrain(ExpressTrain.java:46)
>         at GUIDesign.Express(GUIDesign.java:149)
>         at GUIDesign$1.actionPerformed(GUIDesign.java:80)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)

and more....

Answer (score 0):

Create a method for that.

```java
private static int askIntQuestion(String question, int min, int max) {
    int n = min - 1;
    do {
        try {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            n = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    } while (n < min || n > max);
    return n;
}
```

And then call with:

```java
int waitseconds = askIntQuestion("How many seconds would you like to wait for out of 1 - 7?", 1, 7);
```

As you already know, the `do-while` forces the valid range. Now, the `try-catch` has the purpose to capture exceptions that shows up in the console when the input is not a number or when there was simply no input. The `n` variable is initialized with `min - 1` to ensure it will not exit the loop if a non-numeric input is given. Finally, enclosing all of that in a method makes it much easier to use in the outside as you see with the call.

If you wish, you could change the code to inform the user when he inputs something bad:

```java
private static int askIntQuestion(String question, int min, int max) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (n >= min && n <= max) return n;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You should input a number between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
    }
}
```

Here we don't need the trick to initialize to `min - 1` because the `while` ensures that the only way to exit is in the `return` instruction, which only happens when the input is valid. Otherwise it shows the error message and loops.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd probably want to store the questions in an external file, or database, so that they're not cluttering up the code.  You can read a line from the file and treat that as a question.

Now, if you have to have specific validation logic against it, you do have a bit of code to write to ensure that you have the right validation for the right question, but I would imagine it'd be something along the lines of this:

```
BOUND 1,8 How many hours do you sleep for? between 1-8?
```

...with an `enum` of the type of constraint you have in the file, the limitations separated by a comma, and the actual question.

I won't engineer that solution for you, but I'd strongly encourage you to come up with something that suits you and your understanding of Java better.

Next, the way that `Integer#parseInt()` works is that it will attempt to parse the input as an integer, or blow up sky high if it's not remotely numeric (i.e. `"$"`).

That **blowing up** is actually easy to recover from - you can use a `try...catch` statement 
 to recover from that method failing to convert the input to an `Integer`, and an infinite loop to keep asking for input if the answer isn't parsed correctly:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        Integer waitseconds = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many seconds would you like to wait for out of 1 - 7?"));
        if(waitseconds < 1 || waitseconds > 10) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input; please try again.");
    }
}
```

Your last question:  the errors are the result of you inputting literally nothing to the input dialog, so when it is brought back to the program, you get those exceptions.  You could add a null check before you attempt to parse the integer, which would be wise to do anyway.